# GenericRepository TEntity change attribute value

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern, code-first

I am using EF 5.0 and the model first approach. I have build a GenericRepository that has the basic get, insert, delete etc statements. Like:

```
public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
{
      dbSet.Add(entity);
}
```

My EF entities all have the attributes Modified and ModifiedBy. Now I want to change this values everytime I save an entity. 
Is it possible to modify this two attributes (set the value) without writing an specific implementation all the time?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two options for you to do this, but they both entail either introducing a base type or an interface for all of your entities to cover them in a generic function. I would prefer an interface, although each entity would have to implement it again and again.

Let's say you create

```
interface IAuditable
{
    DateTime Modified { get; set; }
    string ModifiedBy {get; set; } // User id?
}
```

Now you can do:

```
public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
   where TEntity : IAuditable
{
     entity.Modified = DateTime.Now;
     entity.ModifiedBy = ???? // Whatever you get the name from
     ...
}
```

(Same for edit)

You can also subscribe to the context's [`SavingChanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.savingchanges.aspx) event:

```
// In the constructor:
context.SavingChanges += this.context_SavingChanges;

private void context_SavingChanges(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var auditable in context.ObjectStateManager
        .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified)
        .Select(entry => entry.Entity)
        .OfType<IAuditable>)
    {
        auditable.Modified = DateTime.Now;
        auditable.ModifiedBy = ????;
    }
}
```

If you work with `DbContext` you can get to the event by

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.SavingChanges
```

I'd like to add that more reliable time tracking can (and maybe should) be achieved by database triggers. Now you depend on a client's clock.

Comment: The solution is good, I use something similar. +1  But im very curious as why you say  "Now you depend on a client's clock"  Depend on System.DateTime yes, but where is the dependency to client ? Or did you simply mean dependency on the clock of machine where code runs.  In which case yes  it sure does.  There is a dependency injection solution to that.  But that is another topic.

Comment: @soadyp Yes, you're right. The clock of the machine where the code runs. Good to point that out. "Client" is pretty overloaded word.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the following code in your all methods of repository where you want to.

```
     public virtual void Edit(TEntity entity)
     {
          entity.Modified=DateTime.Now;
          entity.ModifiedBy=User.Identity.Name;
          //Other saving to repository code
     }
```

Comment: No Sorry, TEntity is generic and has no Modified or ModifiedBy, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/bb341748.aspx