# Entity Framework 5 Update Procedures with Unmapped Column

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Our architecture is set-up so that every database update, insert and delete are done via Stored Procedures. Along with every update, insert or delete we pass in an ActionId parameter which is unique for the user session, and stored in a log table. The table definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE Member(
    MemberId int primary key identity not null,  
    MemberName nvarchar(100) not null)
```

With an insert stored procedure definition of:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[proc_MemberInsert]  
(  
    @MemberName nvarchar(100),   
    @ActionId int
)  
AS 
BEGIN
INSERT
INTO
    dbo.[Member] (  
    MemberName)   
values (  
    @MemberName)  

INSERT
INTO
    dbo.[Activity] (  
    TableName,
    ActivityId)   
values (  
    'Member',
    @ActivityId)  
END
```

How can I execute an Insert against the Member entity using a stored procedure, and pass in an addition parameter, since this ActivityId is not a part of the entity or any table?

Comment: Short answer: not possible. The signature of the (insert and edit) sprocs should match with the entity properties. Maybe you can add an `ActivityId` to your entities and fill in in the context's `SavingChanges` event? (a bit like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14667122/861716).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gert is correct that this is not easily possible. Oracle does provide the ability to log an activity Id for an entire user session, and we are connecting to Oracle as the user. So we ended up adding the ActivityId to all select procedures, and in the select mapping that ActivityId to the session (since we always have a select before performing any edits). In this case the ActivityId value exists, and we add it to the log, and everything works perfectly.